# Find keyword in a dataframe and taking those values into another dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am needing help finding keywords in a dataframe with nan values since I keep running into a error. There is more data above walmart, and I am trying to find a keyword "walmart" and take the value from that row where walmart is at and go down until I find the keyword "Jan Sales" twice and grab the data one row above where the second "Jan sales" is found.

| Name | iphone 12 | iphone 12 pro max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Walmart** | nan | nan |
| Jan Sales | 150 | 78 |
| Feb Sales | 40 | 44 |
| **BestBuy** | nan | nan |
| Jan Sales | 34 | 45 |
| Feb Sales | 44 | 5 |

So it should grab

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to select al the "Sales" rows below "Walmart", so do that directly:

```
# is the row a "Sales" row?
m1 = df['Name'].str.endswith(' Sales')
# Select all "Sales" rows below "Walmart"
m2 = df['Name'].mask(m1).ffill().eq('Walmart')

out = df[m2]
```

Output:

```
        Name  iphone 12  iphone 12 pro max
0    Walmart        NaN                NaN
1  Jan Sales      150.0               78.0
2  Feb Sales       40.0               44.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @mozway's comment, if all values except for the Name column are NaN, it can be applied in various cases.

```
x='Walmart'
df[df['Name'].where(df.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis=1)).ffill().eq(x)]
```

output:

```
    Name        iphone_12   iphone_12_pro_max
0   Walmart     NaN         NaN
1   Jan_Sales   150.0       78.0
2   Feb_Sales   40.0        44.0
```